# Ghidra - Export namespaces

Tags: disassembly, c++, ghidra

I am currently learning to use ghidra, and I found the Symbol Tree.

Ghidra found some namespaces that I would like to export.
These namespaces don't even have to be readable, just reusable, such that I can use them in another application.

Is there any way in Ghidra to export those namespaces in a reusable form? And if not, what would be my best bet of achieving this?

Some additional information:

- The namespace is written in Visual C++ or C++.
- The application is running on windows, and so is Ghidra.

If any more information or clarification is needed, please tell me.